# want to fetch CPU time, got

Tags: c, cpu-time

```
#ifdef WIN32
#else
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/timeb.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

int main()
{
 long time_ms;
#ifdef WIN32
struct _timeb timebuffer;
_ftime( &timebuffer );
time_ms = (long)timebuffer.time * 1000 + (long)timebuffer.millitm;
printf("Windows timing %ld", time_ms);

#else
struct timeval t1;
struct timezone tz;
gettimeofday(&t1, &tz);
time_ms = (t1.tv_sec) * 1000 + t1.tv_usec / 1000;
    printf("Other timing %ld", time_ms);
 #endif
//    return time_ms;
}`
```

Error:
[image]

this is part of complete code, but when i run individually got same error, unable to find solution.
i attached error screen shot

Comment: Remove the `#ifdef WIN32` and `#else` and `#endif`.

Comment: You are not including any files for the Windows compilation. So it does not recognize the structures and functions.

Comment: The screenshot shows you're using Dev-C++. Don't. Use CodeBlocks w/ MinGW or an Express/Community edition of Visual Studio (both free).

Answer (score 0):

[`gettimeofday`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) does not give you the time the CPU has spent on the process, it gives you the real time in the real world.  What you want is [`clock`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_clock.htm).  This will tell you the amount of processing time the program has used.  It is a standard ISO C function and should work on any C compiler.

Note that the value it returns is in clock ticks.  To get seconds you must divide it by CLOCKS_PER_SEC.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    clock_t cpu_time;

    for( int i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        cpu_time = clock();

        printf("CPU time used since program start is: %d clocks or %f seconds\n",
               (int)cpu_time,
               (float)cpu_time / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
        );
    }
}
```